# What are good, free online video tutorials for dSLR beginners?

Tags: video, tutorial, course

I have just bought a new DSLR, after some years of point-and-shoot photography.

Are there any good free, online video tutorials or courses for the basics?

Comment: It is hard for stack exchange to answer questions that have "good" in the title, unless they are a community wiki.

Comment: I would just search Google for "youtube dslr basics". The question is no different if you replace DSLR with photography, SLR, cameras, or any model of DSLR really.

Comment: @dpollitt: 1. Please make a CW (I don't have permissions). 2. This comment applies to many questions here. Google lacks the voting mechanism and the professional commentary of the SE network. Having some good answers and comments from professionals, categorizing and valuating the videos, is far more efficient than simple searching.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: I think it's unlikely that anyone has really spent a lot of time watching and evaluating a meaningful number of introductory videos. (Why would someone do that?) At best, there will be a grab-bag of various "well, I found this one good" answers, maybe with "me too" comments. This isn't a _bad_ question, it's just not a Stack Exchange one. Maybe it could be a CW, but I'll be surprised if it gets good results. Most such list-of-best-resources CW questions just don't end up with stellar collections of answers.

Comment: But it's not all negativity around here. Where SE shines is in practical answers. Rather than looking for a video, try getting out and working with your new DSLR. When you come across specific questions, ask 'em here, and I _guaruhntee_ helpful and quick results.

Comment: Annnd finally, we've actually got a few similar existing "best tutorial" questions — http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14143/what-is-the-best-tutorial-to-learn-photography and  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11848/what-are-good-online-or-dvd-tutorials-for-my-new-nikon-d7000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a happy customer of Adorama, and they have a whole slew of online videos at [Adorama Learning Center](http://www.adorama.com/alc/)

My wife has recently decided that she wants to buy her first dSLR and I pointed her at the [D3100 review](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTaBp-W7isE)  and she liked it because rather than facts and figures, it described more how you would use the camera in terms that she could understand.

Comment: Thank you! It's a great source, beginning from the very basics: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnVzXVsKdXU